# High order function returning result and modified itself

Tags: haskell

My goal is to create function, which take argument, compute result and return it in tuple with modified itself.

My first try looked like this:

```
f x = (x,f') where
    f' y = (y+1,f') 

cl num func = let (nu,fu) = func num in nu:fu num
```

My desired result if I call function cl with 0 and f was

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 ... infinity]
```

Unfortunately, haskell cannot construct infinite type. It is hard for me to devise another way of doing it. Maybe, I'm just looking at problem from the bad side, thats why I posted this question.

EDIT:
This is the state of my functions:

```
newtype InFun = InFun { innf :: Int -> (Int,InFun) }

efunc x = (x,InFun deep) where
    deep y = (y+1, InFun deep)

crli n (InFun f) = let (n',f') = f n in n':crli n f'

main = putStrLn $ show (take 10 (crli 0 (InFun efunc)))
```

Result is [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]. That's better, But, I want the modification made by deep function recursive.

Comment: Can you explain how you want to use this function? It would help us find ways to solve your original problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you are looking for

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype F = F { f :: Int -> (Int, F) }

g y = (y + 1, F g)
```

then

```
*Main> fst $ (f $ snd $ g 3) 4
5
```

or

```
*Main> map fst $ take 10 $ iterate (\(x, F h) -> h x) (g 0)
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

or more complex modification (currying)

```
h = g False
    where g x y = (y', F g')
                  where y' = if x then y + 1
                                  else 2 * y
                        g' = if x then g False
                                  else g True
```

then

```
*Main> map fst $ take 10 $ iterate (\(x, F h) -> h x) (h 0)
[0,1,2,3,6,7,14,15,30,31]
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but, can you in function g return in F modified version of g? This is the core feature which I wanted.

Comment: @Seraph, each returned `g` is "different". Your initial example runs well (`h x = (x, g) where g y = (y + 1, F g)`), let me write other example...

Comment: Thanks, nice example. Now I understand what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iterate`:

```
iterate (+1) 0
```

Comment: I know, I onli tested if I can create infinite datatype.